# Adventure Review Questions

Tags: discussion

We have a question [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49587/what-is-missing-in-my-campaign?noredirect=1#comment100644_49587) that asks for feedback on a proposed adventure arc for a Pathfinder game.

While the question is well written and interesting, I'm affraid that here not really the best place for reviews - It's a bit too broad, and too opinion based, it feels.

How we should proceed here? Close?

Comment: Definitely not a good fit for the site in its current form. They're basically asking us to fill in the gaps to their plot.

Comment: Dang, beat me to it...I'd like to encourage any people who post answers to offer some suggestions on how we could guide this new user.

Comment: I'm starting to feel like a new custom off-topic "This belongs on an RPG forum" close reason might be useful, because of the boilerplate help for askers that appears on custom close reasons. We can word it nicely once and then be done with all these "sorry, forum this instead" comments explaining the closes.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I would back that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Defintely a close.

The OP is asking for a critique without talking about his design intent and the post is entirely composed by the adventure. He needs a forum to be a sounding board for him, not a Q&A site.